# Keep the button focused when click on input: Material-Ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have the next material-ui dialog:

[image]

But when I click on the input field the social button will defocus and I don't want that:

[image]

The button:

```
export const SocialButton = (props: SocialButtonProps) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <IconButton
    centerRipple={true}
    className={classes.socialButton}
    size="small"
    onClick={props.onClick}
    aria-label="add"
    component="span"
    disableRipple
  >
     {props.icon}
  </IconButton>
);
```

};

Style:

```
export const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    socialButton: {
      '&:focus': {
        boxShadow: `0 0 0 0.1rem ${theme.palette.primary.main}`,
      },
    },
  }),
);
```

Component:

```
      <Grid container>
        <Grid item>
          <SocialButton
            icon={<BehanceLogo />}
            onClick={() => setSocialPlatform('behance')}
          />
          ....
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply create an "active" class with that same style and save state (using [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)) of which button should be active.

You could do something like:

```
const [activeButton, setActiveButton] = useState(null)

...

if (activeButton === 'behance')
    behanceStyle = classes.active // Use useStyle to create the 'active' class
          
return (
    <SocialButton
        className={behanceStyle}
        icon={<BehanceLogo />}
        onClick={() => {
            setSocialPlatform('behance')
            setActiveButton('behance')
        }}
    />
  )
```

Comment: you beat me to it... :)